# Redirect request to CDN using nginx

Tags: proxy, nginx, url-rewriting, cdn

I have a couple of server addreses, like cdn1.website.com, cdn2.website.com, cdn3.website.com. Each of them holds simillar files.

Request comes to my server and I want to redirect or rewrite it to a random cdn server.
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try using the [split clients](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSplitClientsModule) module:

```
http {

  # Split clients (approximately) equally based on
  # client ip address
  split_clients $remote_addr $cdn_host {
    33% cdn1;
    33% cdn2;
    - cdn3;
  }

  server {
    server_name example.com;

    # Use the variable defined by the split_clients block to determine
    # the rewritten hostname for requests beginning with /images/
    location /images/ {
      rewrite ^ http://$cdn_host.example.com$request_uri? permanent;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the right solution to the question, but it isn't the best way to do what I expect you actually want.  Specifically, you're trying to offload work from your web servers.  If your application is sending CDN requests to your web server first, then being redirected, you're not really offloading everything to the CDN.  Ideally you'd want your application itself to render links to assets on the CDN directly.  If you use Rails, you can use the built in "asset hosts" feature.  Other frameworks have similar features or you can DIY :)

Comment: I have a doubt regarding this. If you route CDN request through a NGINX or whatever proxy, would one be losing the CDN benefits since the CDN will redirect that request to the nearest CDN surrogate to the proxy physical location?

Comment: Weirdly I'm trying to do exactly the same as a multicdn drop in solution, if you have a customer that wants zero code changes then it would seem to be the only way. If you 301 images they won't come back through the load balancer so you're just adding an extra TCP handshake.

Answer (score 0):

This is of course possible. Nginx comes with load balancing:

```
upstream  mysite  {
   server   www1.mysite.com;
   server   www2.mysite.com;
}
```

This defines 2 servers for load balancing. By default requests will be equally distributed across all defined servers. You can however add weights to the server entries.

Inside your server {} configuration you can now add the following to pass incoming requests to the load balancer (e.g. to load balance all requests for the images directory):

```
location /images/ {
      proxy_pass  http://mysite;
}
```

Have a look at the [documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpUpstreamModule) for a more detailed description.

Comment: I have tried this solution, but upstream isnt located on my server

Comment: This isn't the right solution.  The point of the CDN is to actually offload work from the webserver.  This would actually proxy all requests to the CDN rather than redirect them, which generally renders the CDN useless.